# What is the NP?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, neyman-pearson-lemma

Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d. variables Poisson $(\lambda)$

and $g(λ)=\lambda(c - e^{-cλ})$
c:constant

What is the NP  for 
$H_0:g(λ)=c1$  vs $H_1:g(λ)=c2$      ??

My thought:

*Step 1:*  We prove  (monotone likelihood ratio property)
$$\forall \lambda_2>\lambda_1\:\: \frac{g(x\mid g(λ_2))}{g(x\mid g(λ_1))}$$
and (If I have not done any mistake) I proved
$\frac{g(x\mid g(λ_2))}{g(x\mid g(λ_1))}$ is non-decreasing (increasing) in 
$$T(X)=\sum(X_i)$$

*Step 2* : after this point I am not sure how to continue the function hypothesis "$g(λ)$ confuses me .

Comment: You're comparing two simple hypotheses, and Neyman-Pearson (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman–Pearson_lemma) tells us that in that case the likelihood ratio test is UMP.

Comment: $g(\lambda)=1$ is the same as $\lambda\approx1.349976$ and  and $g(\lambda=2)$ is the same as $\lambda \approx 2.238646.$ So you're testing $\lambda\approx1.349976$ against $\lambda \approx 2.238646.$ After that, the function $g$ no longer matters.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Could you please elaborate on how you found λ1 and λ2 values? for example how would I calculate those only by hand.

Comment: @GAGA : I did it numerically, using software, by the secant method.

Comment: @GAGA Please be careful of making edits that end up making your questions less informative. Your new title is ambiguous. Please make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by observing that $g(\lambda)$ is a monotonically increasing function of $\lambda$.  This implies that for each value of $g(\lambda)$, there will be a unique value of $\lambda$; we can find a unique $\lambda$ such that $g(\lambda)=1$ and another such that $g(\lambda)=2$.  If we find these $\lambda$s, our problem reduces to finding the UMP test for the two point hypotheses associated with those two $\lambda$ values, and the Neyman-Pearson lemma assures us that such a test exists.

Unfortunately, there is no closed-form expression for the inverse function of $g(\lambda) = \lambda(1-e^{-\lambda})$, but we can find it numerically easily enough through any of a number of univariate root-finding algorithms, e.g., interval halving:

$$\lambda_1 = g^{-1}(1) \approx 1.35$$
$$\lambda_2 = g^{-1}(2) \approx 2.239$$

Defining $T(X) = \sum X_i$, as you have done, allows us to write the likelihood ratio for $H_1/H_0$ as:

$$\mathcal{L} = 2^{T(X)}e^{-1} \propto 2^{T(X)}$$

Taking the log of this last expression simplifies things, and is permissible as it is a monotonic transform of the likelihood ratio.  Our task then becomes finding the critical value $c$ for $T(X)$, where, under the null hypothesis, $T(X) \sim \text{Poisson}(g^{-1}(1)n) \approx \text{Poisson}(1.35n)$. If we do not care whether our test is exact, this amounts to finding $\min_c : P(c | n) \geq 1-\alpha$, e.g, if $n=10$ and $\alpha = 0.05$, then $c=20$, as $P(20|13.5)=0.965$ but $P(19|13.5) = 0.942$.

Unfortunately, as $T(X)$ takes on only integer values, there may be no $c$ such that the probability that $T(X) > c$ under $H_0$ is exactly equal to our chosen test level $\alpha$.  If we wish an exact test, we will have to randomize.

Following our example, this randomization results in the following criteria:

$\begin{align}
&\text{If}\,\, T(x) > 20, \text{reject} \,H_0 \\
&\text{If}\,\, T(x) < 20, \text{don't reject}\,H_0 \\
&\text{If}\,\, T(x) = 20, \text{reject}\, H_0\,\text{with probability}={0.95-0.942 \over 0.965-0.942} \approx 0.348
\end{align}$

where the randomization could occur by generating a $U(0,1)$ random number and comparing to the stated probability.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you found λ1 and λ2 values? for example how would I calculate those only by hand.

Comment: You can use a simple root-finding routine to do so, such as interval halving.

Comment: Is it an easier way to just say that the UMP exists without calculating λ1 , λ2  (for example by using the facts  1) g(λ) monotone (non decreasing ) and 2) $H_0:g(λ)\leq1$ vs  $H_0:g(λ)>1$

Comment: Yes, for existence all you really need in this case is that $g(1) \neq g(2)$ and the Neyman-Pearson lemma.  If they aren't equal, then you can find which one maps back to $\lambda = 1$ and which to $\lambda = 2$ (somehow) and Neyman-Pearson gets you the rest of the way there.

Comment: Thank you  . Also is it true that if g(λ) is increasing and λ>0 : that means that the solutions     $λ_2 $ > $λ_1$ for every $λ_1$ , $λ _2$ ?

Comment: where $g(λ)=\lambda(1 - e^{-λ})$

Comment: $H_0: λ =c_1$  vs $H_1:λ=c_2$  where $c_2 > c_1$

Comment: I think you mean $H_0: g(\lambda) = c_1 \dots$, right?  If so, yes, $g(\lambda)$ increasing does imply that $\lambda_2 > \lambda_1$ if $c_2 > c_1$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405891/karlin-rubin-theorem-ump-uniformly-most-powerful-test-is-it-correct#comment758637_405891 is this solution correct ?